# Angular - Download large files from Azure Storage in best secured way

Tags: angular, security, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

We have an angular application that needs to download large files from Azure Storage.

Since the data in these files can contain sensitive data, SAS is not a good solution for us.
We cannot use AD authorization because the users that login to our application are not registered in AD.

How can we achieve the best security with the best performance?

Comment: Could you explain how sensitive data rules out SAS? If you build an API that gives out short lived SAS tokens based on Access Policies, I would think you're good to go. Also: if you're (down)loading the file in Angular, how it got there is no longer important: the sensitive data is already accessible at that point.

Comment: The downloaded sensitive data is exposed only to the user that downloads it, which was authorized with our services.
Our fear is that SAS can be stolen by attackers (even though - in this short period).

Answer (score 0):

***According to my research It may not be possible without using SAS or Azure active directory if Security is required.***

As both SAS and Azure active directory gives security in azure storage account while [Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/authorize-data-access) with Application.

You can see the storage offers to access the data:

[image]

You can also raise support request for the same further clarification.